# Polynomial time for a quadratic equation and linear inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, computational-complexity, operations-research

Does anyone know how to find a feasible solution (or the infeasibility of any solution) in a polynomial time to the following problem:

\begin{align*}
xAx^t = 0, \\
Bx^t = c, \\
x_i \ge 0,
\end{align*}

where A is not definite positive nor definite negative, but it is symmetric.

Comment: You can encode linear programming with binary variables in this form, so it it NP-hard.

Comment: it is less restrictive than binary programming, i don't see it, there is only 1 quadratic equation

Comment: to make a variable binary you need a quadratic equation for each variable $x^2-x=0$

Answer (score 1):

Your model allows writing
$$y_1^2+y_2^2+\ldots+y_n^2=n,$$
$$-1\leq y_i\leq 1$$
which is equivalent to the statement that each $y_i$ is either $1$ or $-1$, so you can produce an arbitrary number of binary variables in the model.

Comment: The quadratic equation is zero not n. Nonetheless thanks for your explanation, I am pretty much convinced now that it is equivalent to binary programming.

Comment: In the sense that $-n$ is on the LHS as a coefficient at $1^2$ for an extra variable equal to 1.